# How to make user active after refreshing page? Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO for real-time communication in my web application. However, whenever a user refreshes the page, they are disconnected from the Socket.IO server and treated as a new connection. I want to maintain the user's activity and keep them active even after refreshing the page. How can I achieve this in Socket.IO?

I would like to ensure that when a user refreshes the page, they remain connected to the Socket.IO server with their existing session intact. This way, they can seamlessly continue their real-time communication and receive updates without any interruption.

Any guidance or code examples on how to implement this functionality using Socket.IO would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I thought about setting a timeout, so every time a user "disconnected" we wait about 10 sec. and if he didn't return it means the user left.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.